# How to change the textbox default size for all textboxes in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I know that i can do this in twig

`{{ form_widget(form.age, { 'attr': {'size': '5'} }) }}`

But what if i want to do it in my form and for all textboxes

Comment: Can't you use a css solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this document, it explains everything about customizing form rendering in symfony:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html

For example, to customize the rendering of the "integer" fields (the textboxes used for "integer" properties), do this:

```
{% form_theme form _self %}

{% block integer_widget %}
    {% spaceless %}
        {% set type = type|default('number') %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'size': '5' }) %}
        {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
    {% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```

You can see how each field is rendered by default in https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig

This will work for all forms in that particular template. If you want to use this customization in several templates you will need to put this in a separate template, it is all explained in the doc

Comment: It does not explain how to set default attribute for all field types.

Comment: Yes, it does. You just have to customize the html used for the field types you want to customize.

Comment: Ah, okay - then I agree :). Could you post the example with customization then?